# Как на js реализовать скрытие блока на время

Tags: javascript

Есть блок. В блоке ссылка. Как реализовать возможность скрытия блока на 2 дня при нажатии на ссылку на `javascript` без `jquery`?

```
<div class="wrapper">...<a href="#">скрыть</a></div>
```

Решил не просить просто так, а немного разобраться.
Получил в итоге код

```
<div id="wrapper" style=""> ... 
<a id="link" href="#" onclick="hide('wrapper')">скрыть</a> 
</div> 

<script> function hide(id) { 
var div = document.getElementById(id) 
if(div.style.display == '') 
div.style.display = 'none' 
else div.style.display = '' } 
</script>
```

Как прикрутить localstorage не знаю

Comment: А что именно у вас не получается? Вы не знаете как скрыть? Вы не знаете как подсчитать и где хранить эти 2 дня?

Comment: Честно говоря я понятия не имею как это сделать

Comment: Уверен, что на сайте фриланса всё сделают за вас и как вам нужно. Здесь же помогают решить проблему, а не делают всё вместо вас

Comment: Спасибо, хоть и жестко

Comment: Да можно просто  `setTimout-ом`  реализовать

Comment: @Air, `setTimout` не подойдёт. Если не критично, что пользователь может это обойти, то можно в storage сохранить дату, когда кнопка должна быть показана. Если критично, то сохранять дату на сервере. А уж скрыть или показать элемент - `display: none`

Comment: Можно все......

Comment: @WA-A, для того что бы помогли, хотя бы расскажи на чем сервер написан

Comment: В общем почитал мануалы
Получил вот такой код.
<div id="wrapper" style="">
...
<a id="link" href="#" onclick="hide('wrapper')">Шифр цезаря</a>
</div>
<script>
function hide(id)
{
    var div = document.getElementById(id)
    if(div.style.display == '') 
        div.style.display = 'none'
    else 
        div.style.display = ''
}
</script>

Как время прикрутить не знаю. Думаю можно хранить в storage, не критично.

Comment: на два дня конкретному пользователю или всем?

Comment: всё понял, тому, кто на ссылку нажал

Comment: Конкретному, тому, кто нажал на ссылку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И вот таким образом у человека, нажавшего на ссылку, блок перестанет появляться.

```js
//берём ссылку
let butt=document.getElementById('link'),
//берём блок
block=document.getElementById('sneakyblock'),
//узнаём значение таймера в локальном хранилище
exp=window.localStorage.getItem('hidingexpire'),
//это сколько милисекунд в одном дне
dailyms=86400000
//если таймера нет или он уже истёк - показываем блок
if(!exp||exp<new Date().getTime()) block.style.display='block'
//событие по нажатию на ссылку
butt.onclick=()=>{
  //скрываем блок
 block.style.display='none'
  //заводим таймер
 window.localStorage.setItem('hidingexpire',new Date().getTime()+dailyms*2)
}
```

```css
#sneakyblock{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background:red;
 }
```

```html
<div id="sneakyblock" style="display:none"></div>
<a id="link" href="#">скрыть</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, сработало!

Comment: @WA-A отлично, рад помочь! Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, то будьте добры, нажмите на галку слева от ответа и поставьте треугольник вверх. Я очень жажду этих плюсиков в карму >:)

Comment: Сделано, но пишет, что ответ записан, но не отображается из-за репутации менее 15-ти,

Comment: Подниму, обязательно отмечу еще раз

Comment: @WA-A оки доки локи

Comment: @WA-A ух ты, клёво, не забыл про меня всётаки!

Comment: На за что. Еще раз спасибо!